# Union of two SQL queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem to get to SQL queries into one, the problem is that I want `FirstName, LastName` twice. First the names from `tblUploadedImages` and then the names from `tblImageParticipants`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetFeaturedImages
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
       tblUser.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader, 
       tblUser.LastName AS LastNameUploader, 
       tblUser.UserID AS UserIDUploader 
   FROM 
       tblUploadedImages 
   INNER JOIN 
       tblUser ON tblUploadedImages.UserID = tblUser.UserID

   SELECT        
        tblUploadedImages.ImgUrl, 
        tblUploadedImages.ImgUrlOriginal, 
        tblUploadedImages.Description, 
        tblUploadedImages.ImageID, 
        tblUser.FirstName, 
        tblUser.LastName, 
        tblUploadedImages.UserID AS Uploader, 
        tblImageParticipants.UserID AS Participants
   FROM            
        tblImageParticipants  
   INNER JOIN
        tblUploadedImages ON tblImageParticipants.ImageID = tblUploadedImages.ImageID
   INNER JOIN
        tblUser ON tblImageParticipants.UserID = tblUser.UserID
   ORDER BY 
        tblUploadedImages.Added
END
```

I get the right results its just that I want it in one SQL query. How can I do that?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `UNION ALL`. A `UNION` removes the duplicates. What I think you want is not to remove the duplicates.

```
SELECT 
   tblUser.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader, 
   tblUser.LastName AS LastNameUploader, 
   tblUser.UserID AS UserIDUploader 
FROM 
   tblUploadedImages 
INNER JOIN 
   tblUser ON tblUploadedImages.UserID = tblUser.UserID

UNION ALL

SELECT        
    tblUser.FirstName, 
    tblUser.LastName, 
    tblUploadedImages.UserID AS Uploader
FROM            
    tblImageParticipants  
INNER JOIN
    tblUploadedImages ON tblImageParticipants.ImageID = tblUploadedImages.ImageID
INNER JOIN
    tblUser ON tblImageParticipants.UserID = tblUser.UserID
ORDER BY 
    tblUploadedImages.Added
```

It might also be a *god idé* to have something so you know which is which. You can add an additional column for that like this:

```
SELECT 
   tblUser.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader, 
   tblUser.LastName AS LastNameUploader, 
   tblUser.UserID AS UserIDUploader,
   'UploadedImages' AS Type
FROM 
   tblUploadedImages 
INNER JOIN 
   tblUser ON tblUploadedImages.UserID = tblUser.UserID

UNION ALL

SELECT        
    tblUser.FirstName, 
    tblUser.LastName, 
    tblUploadedImages.UserID AS Uploader,
    'ImageParticipants' AS Type
FROM            
    tblImageParticipants  
INNER JOIN
    tblUploadedImages ON tblImageParticipants.ImageID = tblUploadedImages.ImageID
INNER JOIN
    tblUser ON tblImageParticipants.UserID = tblUser.UserID
ORDER BY 
    tblUploadedImages.Added
```

I hope this helps

Comment: @user1007103 : remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two queries with `UNION`, but the columns have to match (number of columns and their types).

So your query would have to look like this:

```
SELECT 
   tblUser.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader, 
   tblUser.LastName AS LastNameUploader, 
   tblUser.UserID AS UserIDUploader 
FROM 
   tblUploadedImages 
INNER JOIN 
   tblUser ON tblUploadedImages.UserID = tblUser.UserID

UNION

SELECT        
    tblUser.FirstName, 
    tblUser.LastName, 
    tblUploadedImages.UserID AS Uploader
FROM            
    tblImageParticipants  
INNER JOIN
    tblUploadedImages ON tblImageParticipants.ImageID = tblUploadedImages.ImageID
INNER JOIN
    tblUser ON tblImageParticipants.UserID = tblUser.UserID
ORDER BY 
    tblUploadedImages.Added
```

I omitted the additional columns from the second query, so that both queries have the same number of columns.

If you need the additional columns from the second query as well, you can leave the second query as it is, but add "dummy" columns to the first query:

```
SELECT 
   '' as ImgUrl,
   '' as ImgUrlOriginal,
   '' as Description,
   0 as ImageID,
   tblUser.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader, 
   tblUser.LastName AS LastNameUploader, 
   tblUser.UserID AS UserIDUploader,
   0 as Participants
FROM 
   tblUploadedImages 
INNER JOIN 
   tblUser ON tblUploadedImages.UserID = tblUser.UserID
```

(SQL Server uses the column names from the first query, hence the aliases)

Comment: Okey, I will try that. I dont have to use UNION, if there is another way, maybe my heading was missleading but I will try this.

Comment: I have tried it now and I dont get the names on both the uploader and the imageparticipant. The tblUser.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader writes over the FirstNameParticipant

Comment: I don't see a FirstNameParticipant anywhere. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `tblUploadedImages` table in your 2nd query, like this:

```
SELECT        
        tblUploadedImages.ImgUrl, 
        tblUploadedImages.ImgUrlOriginal, 
        tblUploadedImages.Description, 
        tblUploadedImages.ImageID, 
        tblUser.FirstName, 
        tblUser.LastName, 
        tblUploadedImages.UserID AS Uploader, 
        tblImageParticipants.UserID AS Participants,
        u.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader,
        u.LastName AS LastNameUploader
   FROM            
        tblImageParticipants  
   INNER JOIN
        tblUploadedImages ON tblImageParticipants.ImageID = tblUploadedImages.ImageID
   INNER JOIN
        tblUser ON tblImageParticipants.UserID = tblUser.UserID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
        tblUploadedImages i ON i.UserID = tblUser.UserID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
        tblUser u ON u.UserID = i.UserID
   ORDER BY 
        tblUploadedImages.Added
```

You might need to assign the other tables an alias to avoid ambiguity, but you can try it without first.

Comment: I still have two querys even if I left outer join on the tblImageParticipants. If the query is tblUser.FirstName AS FirstNameUploader, tblUser.FirstName AS Participant FROM tblUploadedImages they still have the same value.

Comment: Keep all the code you have now in 2nd query the same, but add a left out join to tblImageParticipants and a second one to tblUser, and that should be what you want. I can type it out when I get to a real computer. You can alias as tblUser2.firstName or whatever.

Comment: Okey, I'll wait until you get to a real computer, I cant get it together.